# Write to File in Ruby Script Using Cron Job

Tags: ruby, cron

I'm trying to write a cron job for a Ruby script that writes to a file. Separately they work fine. The cron job itself actually runs. And when I run the script, the content is outputted to the file. However, the cron job does not actually write to the file. I can see the output in my cron job mail directory but not in the folder that I specified in my script. Is there any reason a cron job would not write to a local file? 
Here is what the job looks like:

`*/1 * * * * bash -lc "ruby /Users/me/path/reddit_notify.rb"`

Again, this runs. Should I try outputting the results of the cron job to a file directly, instead of writing to a file in the script?

Thanks

Comment: what is the code of your ruby file? could the file written to a different location than the one you think?

Comment: How about permissions?

Comment: it's possible that it could be going to a different location, but i don't believe so.